# Opening multiple files from cmd line split across tabs in different windows

Tags: vim

Does vim support opening a set of files in separate windows distributed across tabs? e.g. say I want to open 10 files in 5 tabs with 2 windows each.

Tried `vim -p5 -o2 *abc*` and `vim -o2 -p5 *abc*`, but it doesn't seem to consider both options.

VIM version - 7.4
OS - RHEL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not as easy as combining the existing `-o` and `-p` command-line arguments. You have to explicitly pass the corresponding `:split` and `:tabedit` commands. For example:

```
vim file1 -c "botright split file2" -c "tabnew file3" -c "botright split file4"
```